# Getting username of current user in kernel space

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I'm trying to implement a system call which prints hello "current username". I tried using getpwuid(getuid()) but didn't work cause I was unable to include pwd.h or unistd.h or sys/types.h. I currently have no idea how to do the work.

Comment: why are you trying to do this? it's almost guaranteed to be a bad idea

Comment: It's simple. A hw I got wants me to implement this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux kernel has no notion about *username*; it knows only user identificator (*uid*).

Mapping from uid to username is contained in *user database*, which is stored as a file `/etc/passwd`. You need to parse this file for extract username.

Comment: thank you, and is there any source(such as online guides or books) I can begin with? @Tsyvarev

Comment: Just google "/etc/passwd format", so you will know format of the user database file. (The format is actually easy for parsing). If you are asking about reading files from kernel space, use google too.